# Angular 16 feature module routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I have an Angular 16 app where I am adding a feature module which is currently already working, but I am struggling with the routing.

This is part of the current route configuration in `app-routing.module.ts`.

```
...

{
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardPageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'machines',
    loadChildren: () =>
        import('./app-machines.module').then(
            (m) => m.AppMachinesComponentsModule,
        )
}

...
```

This is the current and working routing configuration of the feature module `app-machines-routing.module.ts`:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: '',
        component: MyMachinesPageComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'details/:machineNumber',
        component: MachineDetailPageComponent
    }
])
```

The routes are stored in an enum like that:

```
export enum AppRoutes {
    ...
    UserMachines = 'machines',
    UserMachinesDetails = 'machines/details/:machineNumber',
    ...
}
```

I like to use this enum in `app-routing.module.ts` and in my `app-machines-routing.module.ts` for the route paths. This is not possible, because the feature routing module cannot contain the prefix `machines`, otherwise the route is not found. Is there a possibility to have the same paths in both routing modules?

Answer (score 0):

But all you need to do is add one more `ENUM` for the blank route like so

```
export enum AppRoutes {
    ...
    Dashboard = 'dashboard',
    UserMachinesLazyRoute = 'machines',
    UserMachines = '',
    UserMachinesDetails = 'details/:machineNumber',
    ...
}
```

Then the routing will be

#### app-machines-routing.module.ts:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: AppRoutes.UserMachines,
        component: MyMachinesPageComponent
    },
    {
        path: AppRoutes.UserMachinesDetails,
        component: MachineDetailPageComponent
    }
])
```

#### app-routing.module.ts

```
...

{
    path: AppRoutes.Dashboard,
    component: DashboardPageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: AppRoutes.UserMachinesLazyRoute,
    loadChildren: () =>
        import('./app-machines.module').then(
            (m) => m.AppMachinesComponentsModule,
        )
}

...
```

There is another way to do it, but the top method is better and helps with readability and overall the better method

#### enum

```
export enum AppRoutes {
    ...
    Dashboard = 'dashboard',
    UserMachinesLazyRoute = '',
    UserMachines = 'machines',
    UserMachinesDetails = 'machines/details/:machineNumber',
    ...
}
```

#### app-routing.module.ts

```
...

{
    path: AppRoutes.Dashboard,
    component: DashboardPageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: AppRoutes.UserMachinesLazyRoute,
    loadChildren: () =>
        import('./app-machines.module').then(
            (m) => m.AppMachinesComponentsModule,
        )
}

...
```

#### app-machines-routing.module.ts:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: AppRoutes.UserMachines,
        component: MyMachinesPageComponent
    },
    {
        path: AppRoutes.UserMachinesDetails,
        component: MachineDetailPageComponent
    }
])
```

Comment: The second one does not work if there would be a second feature module where I like to the same thing, right? Then I would have two "empty" routes and Angular could not decide which module to load or even worse it would load both. I had already implemented your first suggestion, but then I recognized that the routes are not unique for sure. There could be multiple feature modules with the same feature routes (url parts without `LazyRoute`), or do I miss something?